# Adding controls to a custom form

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls

I created a custom form (FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None).

I draw my own caption bar at the top with my own custom caption buttons (Close, Maximize ...).

Now my only problem is adding normal user controls to that form. If I give these controls a location, the locations are relative to the form's top (including the caption bar).

I override the default ClientSize & ClientRectangle using the 'new' keyword, which allows me to adjust it (thus removing the caption bar out of it).

This does not seem to work and I haven't been able to figure out how to do this properly without 'hacking' the ControlAdded event (which is still buggy).

```
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
        if (e.Control.GetType() != typeof(VlufiCaptionButton /* Caption buttons: close, minimize & maximize, should not be included */))
        {
            e.Control.Location = new Point(e.Control.Location.X + ClientRectangle.X, e.Control.Location.Y + ClientRectangle.Y);
            e.Control.LocationChanged += Control_LocationChanged;
        }
    }
    private void Control_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!childControlLocationChangedHandled)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("changing");
            Control cControl = (Control)sender;
            childControlLocationChangedHandled = true;
            cControl.Location = new Point(cControl.Location.X + ClientRectangle.X, cControl.Location.Y + ClientRectangle.Y);
        }
        else
            childControlLocationChangedHandled = false;
    }
```

This is the code I currently use, but it's superbuggy & I'm still having other problems with my customly drawn border.

Does anybody know how I should correctly handle this ?

**I found a decent solution:** I added a ContainerControl to the form & I position & size this according to the form, then whenever adding a control to the form, it should be added to the ContainerControl. Still not a proper solution, but it's the best one so far.

I'd still appreciate if someone came up with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

read comments for detail:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int dy = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //i add a panel to top form
            //( for simulating your caption bar) and get its height
            dy = panel1.Height; //for yours its your caption bar height
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //adding button control between form top and panel end area
            //( simulate in your caption bar )
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X+40,panel1.Location.Y+10);
            btn.Text = "Salam";
            this.Controls.Add(btn);
        }
        //in control added event i add dy ( height of ignored area) to control Location
        private void Form1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Control.Location = new Point(e.Control.Location.X, e.Control.Location.Y + dy);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the code, that is what I am doing .. It brings a lot of bugs when changing the location at runtime & when resizing the form

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand a word of what you are saying, what is your solution exactly ?

Comment: That's kind of what I was doing in my example code ? Also this method doesn't support docking, etc .. The last solution I found kind of does, I'm sticking with it unless someone can give another better solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok after all, I have finally found a working and pretty nice solution.

What I did is override the Controls property of my custom Form, using my own custom ControlCollection.

So this is what I got in my custom form:

```
public Control.ControlCollection RealControls
{
    get
    {
        return base.Controls;
    }
}
public new CustomControlCollection Controls { get; private set; }

public ContainerControl ControlContainer { get; set; }
```

And this is the custom ControlCollection:

```
public class CustomControlCollection 
{
    public VlufiForm Owner { get; private set; }
    public CustomControlCollection (VlufiForm pOwner)
    {
        Owner = pOwner;
    }
    public void Add(Control c)
    {
        Add(c, false);
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Owner.ControlContainer.Controls.Count;
        }
    }
    public Control this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return Owner.ControlContainer.Controls[index];
        }
    }
    public void Add(Control c, bool isUsable)
    {
        if (isUsable)
            Owner.RealControls.Add(c);
        else
            Owner.ControlContainer.Controls.Add(c);
    }
    public void SetChildIndex(Control c, int nIndex)
    {
        Owner.ControlContainer.Controls.SetChildIndex(c, nIndex);
    }
}
```

This is just an example custom control collection, you could add more methods in it (thus kind of inheriting ControlCollection more).
I haven't found any bugs in this system yet, it works perfectly at the moment.

EDIT: found a bug, if you dock a control in Visual Studio's Designer Mode, it will dock in the whole form, this doesn't appear when running though.